# Como imprimir um vetor de listas (um ponteiro para uma lista)

Tags: c++

Olá, gostaria de saber como eu posso imprimir um ponteiro para uma lista, como um vetor de listas. Fiz um ponteiro apontando para list e não sei como imprimir esses valores. Tentei usando um iterator para cada posição do vetor e imprimindo do inicio ao fim da lista, porém não consegui. Parece algo simples, mas não eu estou conseguindo fazer isso. Alguém conhece uma maneira de como se fazer isso? Segue o código:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <list>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    list<int> *adjV;
    list<int>::iterator it;

    adjV[0].push_back(10);
    adjV[0].push_front(20);
    adjV[0].push_back(30);

    adjV[1].push_back(45);
    adjV[1].push_front(55);
    adjV[1].push_back(65);

    adjV[2].push_back(80);
    adjV[2].push_front(90);
    adjV[2].push_back(100);

    for (it = adjV[0].begin(); it != adjV[0].end(); it++)
        cout << *it << endl;

    for (it = adjV[1].begin(); it != adjV[1].end(); it++)
        cout << *it << endl;

    for (it = adjV[2].begin(); it != adjV[2].end(); it++)
        cout << *it << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Ocorre um erro segmentation fault (core dumped) quando executa.

Answer (score 1):

Está a faltar a inicialização do vetor de listas:

```
list<int> *adjV = new list<int>[3];
```

Com essa inicialização já obtém o resultado esperado.

No entanto agora pode aproveitar e tornar a escrita em apenas `2` `for` encandeados para simplificar e tornar mais flexivel:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    for (list<int>::iterator it = adjV[i].begin(); it!= adjV[i].end(); ++it){
        cout<<*it<<endl;
    }
}
```

[Veja esta solução no Ideone](https://ideone.com/IOgbGj)

Comment: Deu certo! Valeuu!